# htaccess issue, change '/' to '.'

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my first Question to StackOverflow. I have been working with .htaccess for a PHP application that is currently in development. My Contention is changing a forward slash to a period.

I have had no Joy so far, currently my code looks like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_-]+)?$ app/account/?account_name=$1 [NC,L]
```

The above is taking away the 'app/account/?account_name=account_name' and allowing displaying the following : www.exampleurl.com/examplename. This is fine, but is there anyway to change my code so instead of /examplename it states www.exampleurl.com.examplename ? I have spent some time googling the answer to no avail.

If anyone can give me some guidance that would be fantastic, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a real replace, but what you can *if* the nesting is limited to some number (let's say 3) is provide multiple rules each dealing with specific nesting level:

```
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*) /$1.$2.$3 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*) /$1.$2 [L,QSA]
 # third rule is not needed, because when there is only one level, there is nothing to replace
```

What you need to make sure is that the rules are in *descending* order of the nesting levels (`L` flag ensures processing is stopped on a level that is matched)

Comment: Thankyou Poncha, I will be trying this within the next few days and see if the solution works.